# Loading a GeoJSON layer in QGIS from localhost

Tags: qgis, geojson

I have been using the Protocol option for adding a new vector layer in QGIS and it works great for loading GeoJSON from a remote server using a URL. However, when I try loading the same data from a localhost tomcat service I always get an "Invalid Data Source" error.

Is there any way to load from the localhost service, or is it only possible from remote web sites, or does it not allow the specifying of a port number? I have tried http://localhost:8082/..., http://127.0.0.1:8082/... and http://0.0.0.0:8082/... but all give the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, after spending an hour looking and not finding it, of course 2 minutes after posting the question I see that the problem is that I was passing a | character rather than the encoded %7C value  -.-